# kde5/plasma5/kubuntu: how to list kreadconfig5 all available config groups

Tags: kubuntu, kde5, plasma5

I’m new to KDE5/Plasma5. I’ve recently installed Kubuntu 17.10 am came from Gnome 3.

I’d like to list all available config groups (not to confuse them with user groups).

In Gnome 3 I used `gsettings` (and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/155321/279745) script) to list all available schemas and their keys with current (or default) values and their types.

I’d like to achieve something just like that.

I’m using Kubuntu 17.10 and plasmashell 5.10.5.

If there is any other method of reading/writing all (or at least most of) system settings, that’d be a solution, too.